# Git fetch repeatedly tells me about the same new branch

Tags: git

On one particular repo, when I run

```
git fetch
```

It does all the stuff it's supposed to do, but also reports:

```
 * [new branch]      Story/abc-123 -> origin/Story/abc-123
```

*every* single time.

if I run git branch -r | grep abc-123, it yields:

```
origin/story/abc-123
```

Note that in the output from the fetch, 'Story' is capitalized, but in the branch -r output it is not.  The problem seems to be local.  I don't have this issue if I make a new clone of the repo elsewhere, but I'd rather not go down this road if I can avoid it.

Is there any way to make it stop doing this?

Comment: What does `git branch | grep ...` report?

Comment: Are you using a case-insensitive filesystem like OSX?

Comment: @AndrewC Yes.  And until about 5 minutes ago I would have sworn OSX was case sensitive.

Comment: @isherwood the branch doesn't exist locally.  git branch | grep abc-123 (with or without -i) yields nothing.

Comment: Unfortunately that's the end of my ability to help other than saying "I've heard about all sorts of problems like this on OSX and googling for that specifically might help"

Comment: @AndrewC You've at least clued me into the problem, thanks.  Googling didn't help much, but when I check the repo via github, it's Story/abc-123, and it's the only branch with a capital S.  It looks like git stores the refs locally as files, which is IMHO the source of the problem (keeps not seeing 'Story/' locally, tries to write to it, and stuff gets written to 'story/')  I think.  Still don't know how to fix it though.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but you can rename local branches and change the case while doing so: http://tosbourn.com/git-branches-seem-to-be-case-insensitive/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem here is that your `./git/refs` directory is in a different case for part of the branch name compared to the actual remote.  I.e., git branch thinks the branch is lower case:

```
$git branch 
...
origin/story/abc-123
...
```

But your copy of the refs thinks the story directory is upper case:

```
$ls .git/refs/remotes/origin
...
Story
...
```

Apparently you can just delete the entire refs directory and git will regenerate it, but because I was a coward I just fixed it by renaming the offending directory:

```
mv .git/refs/remotes/origin/Story .git/refs/remotes/origin/story
```

Comment: Moving (renaming) the file didn't work for me but deleting the `.git/refs/remotes/origin` directory did. Still... use care whenever `rm -rf` is involved.